# Impala max() over a window clause

Tags: sql, impala

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT name, 
       time, 
       MAX(number) OVER (PARTITION BY name 
                         ORDER BY time 
                         ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM some_table
```

For some reason, aggregating over a fixed window isn't implemented for MAX(), as I get the following error:

```
'max(number)' is only supported with an UNBOUNDED PRECEDING start bound
```

(Replacing `MAX` with `SUM` works as one would expect.)

Is there a workaround for this? I would also appreciate a rough explanation for why this works for `SUM` or `COUNT` but not `MAX` or `MIN`.

I'm currently using Impala 2.7.0.

Comment: Which version of Impala are you using ?

Comment: Impala 2.7.0; I'll edit this into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.
Try Hive instead of Impala. It doesn't have the issue.

Vincent